# Is it possible to choose a specific WiFi channel in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wifi-configuration

I'm in a hotel and experiencing a very flaky connection.

Looking through WiFi Analyzer (Android) I found that Channel 1 and Channel 14 seem to be the most stable ones.

Is there a way to force Windows to connect only to such channels?

Comment: That is something that is usually configured on the access point, not on the client.

Comment: In fact, it can _only_ be configured on the access point. As a client, you can't communicate with the AP on a different channel than the one it broadcasts and listens on. Your best bet would be asking the hotel staff to change the channel—if they can't or won't, there's not much you can do with regards to that network. You may have better luck tethering to your phone or using a wired connection, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you imagine a WiFi AP is a radio station (which it more or less *is*), you can't listen a radio station at 101.5 FM by going to 92.5 FM.

Likewise, you can't connect to a Wifi AP broadcasting at channel 11 by trying to connect to it on channel 5. It cannot be done.

The reason is because WiFi APs are set to broadcast and receive traffic on a particular channel, and regardless of client settings, that cannot be changed unless you log into the AP and change it.

In your case, the hotel tech team/person would have to change the channel themselves.

---

Now, if you're asking how to restrict Windows so that it only connects to WiFi hotspots that are on a particular channel, that can't be done natively. However there may be a third party tool that could do this for you. I'm not aware of any.